# Unable to revert back to ubuntu-desktop

Tags: system-installation

I was trying to install lamp server and purge. I lost the software updater (Gnome to restart, as it mentioned), I lost ubuntu-desktop and now runing on only cli. I tried sudo apt-get update, facing couple of errors (Temporary failure resolving) like bionic InRelease, stable InRelease, bionic-updates InRelease, bionic-backports InRelease, bionic-security InRelease.

Kindly help me in identifying the root cause. I would appreciate if resolved.

Comment: Temporary errors are usually just a connection problem to the repo servers.  Have you tried sudo apt-get update again?

Comment: Yes, I tried sudo apt-get update again, no luck. I am new to ubuntu. I think I lost complete connection to servers. Can you help me in detial to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

The `update` command only updates the package meta data:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If you want to make sure you have the latest software, you need to use `dist-upgrade` as well:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

You may also just use `upgrade`. However, hat will not install/upgrade system packages such as the kernel.

If you really somehow uninstalled the Ubuntu Desktop (X11) then you can attempt to reinstall with:

```
apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

I have some details on [my Linux blog](https://linux.m2osw.com/installing-ubuntu-server-more) (search on X11).

However, it could also be that you changed the startup scripts and it won't boot in the desktop. If that's the case, you'll need to tweak the boot parameters. I also have some info for 16.04 [on my blog](https://linux.m2osw.com/boot-command-line-console-ubuntu-1604-and-newer). For newer systems, you particularly want to look into the `systemctl` commands (also on that page) such as:

```
sudo systemctl start graphical.target
```

Also newer systems do not make use of Unity. (Well some people are still using Unity... but most of us are using Gnome now.)

---

Now, if your server doesn't connect, you probably have a network setup problem. There can be many reasons for that and it's a quite different question than "I lose the Ubuntu Desktop"...

I suppose you have a newer version of Ubuntu (18.04 or newer? You should specify in your question or use a tag.) The network setup is done in the netplan file:

```
sudo vim /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
```

I also have a page about [setting up netplan](https://linux.m2osw.com/setting-your-static-ip-address-ubuntu-1804) on 18.04+. I think here are two main things that can go wrong: you uninstalled a mandatory element (i.e. the DHCP handler/module) or your settings are wrong, somehow. In most cases, if you can ping an external IP address, but you can't determine a domain name IP address, then your name server info is wrong. I often try something such as:

```
ping example.com
```

where `example.com` is your favorite website (say askubuntu.com). The ping is not likely to work, but if it stays stuck on the first line that's because it can't resolve the name. You can try with an IP address too:

```
ping 1.2.3.4
```

If that works, then the network connection is good, but the name resolution is bad.

You can test with `ping` on another Linux or MS-Windows or MacOS machine. Under Windows you probably have to run a console as an administrator (ping sends a type of packet which require admin rights, even under Unix, but Unix automatically gives you the necessary authorization).

Look for netplan docs and network problems for that one.